# Cambiar valores de una columna en Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Soy nuevo en Bash y estoy intentando cambiar los valores de una variable del archivo data.csv delimitado por comas.
En el dataset tengo la variable sexo con dos posibles valores Male y Female y quisiera transformar los Male en m y los Female en f. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
sex=$(cut -d , -f 5 data.csv) #Obtengo la columna 5 que es la correspondiente a la variable que busco
for i in $sex; do
    if [[$i='Female']]; then
    $i='f'
    fin
done
```

El código me da error y no sé muy bien como modificarlo, quisiera además que el archivo data.csv quede modificado con los cambios que he realizado

Comment: ¿puedes poner un par de lineas de tu csv en la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

### Respuesta actualizada

*Gracias a @fedorqui por su aporte*

Suponiendo que tengas un archivo **data.csv** con este contenido:

```
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,Female,seis
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,Male,seis
```

podrías cambiar los Female y Male de este modo usando **awk** y **cp** (copy) :

```bash
#/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$5=="Female"{$5="f"} $5=="Male"{$5="m"}1' data.csv > tempData.csv

## copiamos el resultado sobreescribiendo el archivo origen
cp tempData.csv data.csv 

# eliminamos el temporal
rm tempData.csv
```

y eso te da este resultado:

```
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,f,seis
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,m,seis
```

### Anterior respuesta

*(no optimizada, aunque también funcionaba)*

```bash
#/bin/bash
awk -F, '{
  if ($5 =="Female") $5 = "f"; 
  if ($5 =="Male") $5 = "m"; 
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      printf $i"'',''"
    }; 
    printf "\n"
  } 
 }' data.csv > tempData.csv 

# limpiamos la coma final y sustituimos data.csv
cat tempData.csv | sed 's/.$//' > data.csv

# eliminamos el temporal
rm tempData.csv
```

y eso te da este resultado:

```
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,f,seis
uno,dos,tres,cuatro,m,seis
```

Si te sirve avisa y lo documento un poco más.

Comment: más idiomático: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$5=="Female"{$5="F"} $5=="Male"{$5="M"}1' fichero`. Todo el bucle que haces es innecesario usando `OFS` para definir el separador de campos de salida.

Comment: @fedorqui pues gracias, y mira que he estado buscando (mal por lo que veo) y no lo habia encontrado.... ya me parecia a mi raro que eso no estuviera contemplado... tan solo conseguia que me lo separara con espacios

Comment: Puedes encontrarlo en la guía de [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) es un joya, se lee muy bien además. También recomiendo [Idiomatic awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/index.html) con multitud de ejemplos de estos.

Comment: @fedorqui de nuevo gracias!  la de idomatic awk no la conocía y la otra me la pasé de largo esta vez (hacia mucho tiempo que no jugaba con awk)